# Dropdowm menu in Vanilla JavaScript - for unknown number of buttons

Tags: javascript

please, can you give me a hint with Vanilla JS?

I have dropdown menu opening via button click and have 2 issues:

1) Dropdown is opening by clicking on button with unique ID. I need to get it **working on Class name, because it have to be working on multiple buttons** - and the number of them is unknown (they will load from REST API). 
In jQuery is it working, but I need it in Vanilla JS.

If I try to select button by Class name, it will return array of buttons, but I don't know how to select from array, which button was being clicked on.

2) **Dropdown menu is opening only on the second click on the button** (and then it is toggling like it should), but the first click doesn't do anything.

My code is here:

```
// select Button - now by ID - but I need unknown number of buttons - from REST API - and the code working for all of them
var btn = document.getElementById("dropBtn1");

// select Dropdown menu - next to the button - to be sure it will open the right menu no matter which button will be pressed
var menu = btn.nextSibling;
while(menu && menu.nodeType != 1) {
    menu = menu.nextSibling
}

//toggle dropdown menu open/close
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (menu.style.display == 'none') {
    menu.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

And working prototype is here on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/vlastapolach/pen/EXdLMy

Please, do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: first time click handler runs menu.style.display is empty, whereas your code is expecting menu.style.display == 'none' so that it can change display to block

Comment: Thank you, you are right. it is now solved according to Jonas - not check for == 'none' but for != 'block'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy, you need a general function that works on the *context* (=this):

```
//toggle dropdown menu open/close
function toggle() {
  var btn=this;

  var menu = btn.nextSibling;
  while(menu && menu.nodeType != 1) {
     menu = menu.nextSibling
  }

  if(!menu) return;

  if (menu.style.display != 'block') {//fix 2)
    menu.style.display = 'block';
  }  else {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Now you can assign this functions as an event handler onto all your elements:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

  document.querySelectorAll(".sth").forEach(function(btn){
     btn.addEventListener("click",toggle,true);
  });
});
```

Note that NodeList.forEach is quite new, may use [].slice to create a real array...

And you need to assign the Handlers to the newly added elements manually, or you need to listen on window and trace back the target:

```
window.onclick=function(event){
  if(event.target.classList.contains("sth")){
   toggle.call(event.target);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you so much. It resolved the first issue - now it is working on all buttons :) Please, can you help me with issue #2? It will open dropdown menu only on second click on the button. And please, issue #3 - is there any easy way how to close the dropdown menu when I click outside the dropdown itself? (now it closes only when I click the button again so I will have 3 dropdowns open at the same time...)

Comment: great, the second issue is done with changing condition to test for 'block' instead of 'none'. Thank you Jonas

Comment: please if you have spare time, can you give me a new hint? Is there any easy way how to close the dropdown menu when I click outside the dropdown itself? (now it closes only when I click the button again so I will have 3 dropdowns open at the same time...)

Comment: @vlasta po actually this is a new question. You may push the element onto an array on open, then inside the global click listener iterate over the array and hide all.

Comment: thank you, I have tried to write it but unfortunately with no luck. I tried to place new question, but it won't let me.. please, can you look at new code if you will see, where am I doing it wrong? https://codepen.io/vlastapolach/pen/rwqKrw

Comment: Wow, Jonas, thats perfect. I can now see, where I was wrong. I have so much to learn yet. Thank you!